# Why run time of the following algorithm is O(1) and not Θ(1)?

Tags: algorithm

Algorithm for Enqueue:

```
ENQUEUE(Q,x)  
1.Q[Q.tail]=x  
2.if Q.tail==Q.length  
3.    Q.tail=1  
4.else Q.tail=Q.tail+1
```

It has time complexity O(1).
My question is why it is not Θ(1) ?

Comment: Do you know the difference?

Comment: This question  is theoretical. Try cs.stackexchange.con.

Comment: Why can't it be both?

Comment: @Leeor As I know Θ(1) means running time is proportional to some constant.And O(1) means running time is at most proportional to some constant.

Comment: Trick question.  It is Θ(1) *and* O(1).

Comment: Sorry I'm going off topic here, is the code emptying the queue once it reaches full size?

Comment: @ Abhishek kindly omit the error checking for overflow

Comment: @tan, can you be O(1) and *not* Θ(1)?

Answer (score 2):

**It is O(1) and Θ(1).** (unless the `x` or `Q.length` has infinite bits.)

---

O(1) means that the algorithm has a time complexity of **at most** a constant. It's the upper bounds.

For your case, let's say the algorithm takes a time `t` to insert `x` into a fixed address(`Q.tail`), and then increase the address by 1. It's easy to see that `t` doesn't increase depending on whatever the `n` or `Q` is, and `t` can't be infinity. So the upper bound of this algorithm is **O(1)**, because:

[image]

And, It's easy to see that no matter what the `n` or `Q` is, `t` must be longer than a constant time to let the machine work. `t` could not be infinitesimal. So the lower bound of this algorithm is **Ω(1)**. it means that the algorithm has a time complexity of **at least** a constant.

[image]

Finally, it's a definition that **if T(F(n)) = O(1) and T(F(n)) = Ω(1), then T(F(n)) = Θ(1)**. (If you forget it, please go through the first chapter of the *Introduction to Algorithm*.)

[image]